# ScalaJson implicit Write, found: Any required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am building a web app using Scala / Play Framework and Reactive Mongo and I want the models to be defined in the database instead of having them hardcoded.
To do so, I am writing a class EntityInstance taking a Sequence of FieldInstance :

```
case class EntityInstance(fields: Seq[FieldInstance])
```

I am trying to accept fields from any types and to convert them to Json : example

```
new FieldInstance("name", "John") | json: { "name": "John" }
new FieldInstance("age", 18) | json: { "age": 18 }
```

At the moment I am trying to accept Strings, Booleans and Integers and if the type is not supported I write some error :

```
new FieldInstance("profilePicture", new Picture("john.jpg") | json: { "profilePicture": "Unsupported type
```

I wrote a FieldInstance class taking a fieldName as a String and a value as any type. As soon as that class is instantiated I cast the value to a known type or to the String describing the error.

```
class FieldInstance(fieldNamec: String, valuec: Any) {
  val fieldName = fieldNamec
  val value = valuec match {
    case v: Int => v
    case v: String => v
    case v: Boolean => v
    case _ => "Unrecognized type"
  }
}
object FieldInstance {
  implicit val fieldInstanceWrites = new Writes[FieldInstance] {
    def writes(fieldInstance: FieldInstance) = Json.obj(
      fieldInstance.fieldName -> fieldInstance.value
    )
  }
}
```

I created a companion object with an implicit Write to json so I can call "Json.toJson()" on an instance of FieldInstance and get a json as described on my examples above.

I get an error : `found: Any required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper`
I understand that it comes from the fact that my value is of type Any but I thought the cast would change that Any to String || Boolean || Int before hitting the Writer.

PS: Ignore the bad naming of the classes, I could not name EntityInstance and FieldInstance, Entity and Field because these as the classes I use to describe my models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix to my problem :
The type matching that I was doing in the class should be done in the implicit Write !

```
class FieldInstance(fieldNamec: String, valuec: Any) {
  val fieldName = fieldNamec
  val value = valuec
  override def toString(): String = "(" + fieldName + "," + value + ")";
}
object FieldInstance {
  implicit val fieldInstanceWrites = new Writes[FieldInstance] {
    def writes(fieldInstance: FieldInstance) =
      fieldInstance.value match {
        case v: Int => Json.obj(fieldInstance.fieldName -> v.asInstanceOf[Int])
        case v: String => Json.obj(fieldInstance.fieldName -> v.asInstanceOf[String])
        case v: Boolean => Json.obj(fieldInstance.fieldName -> v.asInstanceOf[Boolean])
        case _ => Json.obj(fieldInstance.fieldName -> "Unsupported type")
      }
  }
}
```

This code now allows a user to create an EntityInstance with Fields of **Any type** :

```
val ei = new EntityInstance(Seq[FieldInstance](new FieldInstance("name", "George"), new FieldInstance("age", 25), new FieldInstance("married", true)))

println("-- TEST ENTITY INSTANCE TO JSON --")
println(Json.toJson(ei))
```

prints : `{"entity":[{"name":"George"},{"age":25},{"married":true}]}`

Here is my EntityInstance code if you are trying to test it :

```
case class EntityInstance(fields: Seq[FieldInstance])
object EntityInstance {
  implicit val EntityInstanceWrites = new Writes[EntityInstance] {
    def writes(entityInstance: EntityInstance) =
      Json.obj("entity" -> entityInstance.fields)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It *is* returning a String, Int or Boolean but Json.obj is expecting the value parameter of type (String, **JsValueWrapper**)

```
def obj(fields: (String, JsValueWrapper)*): JsObject = JsObject(fields.map(f => (f._1, f._2.asInstanceOf[JsValueWrapperImpl].field)))
```

a quick fix could be to convert the matched value `v` with toJson provided the implicit Writes[T] for type T is available (which they are for String, Int and Boolean)

```
class FieldInstance(fieldNamec: String, valuec: Any) {
  val fieldName = fieldNamec
  val value = valuec match {
    case v: Int => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: String => Json.toJson(v)
    case v: Boolean => Json.toJson(v)
    case _ => Json.toJson("Unrecognized type")
  }
}
```

If you'd like to see which DefaultWrites are available you can browse them in the `play.api.libs.json` package in `trait DefaultWrites`

for example:

```
  /**
   * Serializer for Boolean types.
   */
  implicit object BooleanWrites extends Writes[Boolean] {
    def writes(o: Boolean) = JsBoolean(o)
  }
```

Comment: Writes can take any Scala type, for example it is able to parse my fieldName attribute, the problem here is value is still of type Any when it should be of type Int / String or Boolean.